# Can i use jsf (xhtml pages for vue ) and angularJs in the same time?

Tags: angularjs, primefaces, xhtml

i' am developing a JEE project by using JSF with primefaces , Spring AND HIBERNATE  !
for vues pages can i use angularJS  and bootstrap in a facelet ( xhtml page ) ? 
thank you :)

Comment: http://www.angularfaces.com

Comment: @med5951 http://www.bootsfaces.net/ is there its design with the help of Bootstrap+JSF and same JSF+AngularJS+Primefaces started PrimeNG http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/ rather then writing lots of JS+CSS+Jquery use these built in API.